# What happened in chromecast receiver than i get didFailToLoadMediaWithError in sender

Tags: chromecast

then i swoosh media to Chromecast, in app "didFailToLoadMediaWithError" delegate call.

didFailToLoadMediaWithError = Error Domain=com.google.GCKError Code=9 "Request is not allowed in this state" UserInfo=0x171871600 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request is not allowed in this state

how it catch this error in receiver side?

in receiver log i get:
 [ 37.552s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomple